# How I can resample raster data infrom 10 meters to 20 meters resolution in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, resampling

I downloaded Sentinel 2A satellite images and some bands are in 10x10 resolution and some bands are in 20x20 meters resolution. I would like to convert bands with 10x10 spatial resolution to 20x20 meters and then to combine them with images that have original 20x20 resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Resample](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00170000009t000000) tool to do exactly that.
[image]

Because you need to resample the raster to a resolution that's an exact multiplication (10 * 2), you needn't worry about spatial mismatch. otherwise, you can set the snap raster in the tool environments

Comment: Just because the new resolution is a multiplicative of the resolution of the other rasters does not mean that the will automatically align. You should always set analysis environment to ensure matching origin coordinates and dimensions. If not ArcGIS will often estimate the origin coordinates and extent which can drop a row or column in the resulting raster. For operations such as this you always want to set the snap, mask and extent environment. Once everything is resampled you  can use the "Composite Bands" tool under ArcToolbox Data Management" to create a raster stack.

Comment: You mention "you always want to set the snap, mask and extent environment". Where I can do that?

Comment: The "Environments..." button on the bottom of the image I attached opens the tool environment setting. There, under "Raster Analysis" and and "Processing Extent" you can set these parameters.